# EFcore2 : Issue with Foreign keys when i seed my database

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I don't understand this conflict in this case.
I have checked what could be the problem but still, now I can't resolve it.

1. This is a one to many relationships, the table "contact" must join the table "client" on the key code client. A client has many contacts, a contact has one client.
2. The client data in the CSV is inserted before
   the contact data and the key exist in the client table.
3. This problem occurs when I seed my database at the app's launch.
   If I insert the same data directly in SQL server management studio there is no
   problem.
4. I think this is not a data "order" problem but probably the way i'm doing it.

I hope you will be able to help me with this. If you need more informations tell me.

Thanks,

### The error :

> Failed executing DbCommand (32ms) [Parameters=[@p0='TEST'' (Size =
>   450), @p1='blabla@gmail.com' (Size = 4000), @p2='NULL'
>   (Size = 4000), @p3='CIEP' (Size = 4000),
>   @p4='0000000000' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text',
>   CommandTimeout='30'] SET NOCOUNT ON; INSERT INTO [Contacts]
>   ([CodeClient], [Email], [GSM], [Nom], [Telephone]) VALUES (@p0, @p1,
>   @p2, @p3, @p4); SELECT [ContactID] FROM [Contacts] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT =
>   1 AND [ContactID] = scope_identity();
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement
>   conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Contacts_Clients_CodeClient". The conflict occurred in database
>   "IOR_Presta_DB", table "dbo.Clients", column 'CodeClient'.

### My DbContext :

```
public class PrestationContext : DbContext
{
    public PrestationContext(DbContextOptions<PrestationContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Prestation> Prestations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Domaine> Domaines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employe> Employes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contrat> Contrats { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) =>
            optionsBuilder
                //Log parameter values
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeDomaine>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.EmployeID, t.DomaineID });

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeDomaine>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Employe)
            .WithMany(p => p.EmployeDomaines)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.EmployeID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeDomaine>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Domaine)
            .WithMany(t => t.EmployeDomaines)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.DomaineID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ClientContrat>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.ClientID, t.ContratID });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ClientContrat>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Client)
            .WithMany(p => p.ClientContrats)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.ClientID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ClientContrat>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Contrat)
            .WithMany(t => t.ClientContrats)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.ContratID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Client)
            .WithMany(co => co.Contacts)
            .HasForeignKey(co => co.CodeClient)
            .HasPrincipalKey(c => c.CodeClient);
    }
}
```

### My class :

```
public class Contact
{
    public long ContactID { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string GSM { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string CodeClient { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }

}

public class Client
{
    public long ClientID { get; set; }
    public string CodeClient { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Adresse { get; set; }
    public bool FeedbackClient { get; set; }
    public bool EncodagePointage { get; set; }

    public ClientContrat[] ClientContrats { get; set; }

    public Contact[] Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

### The way i seed my database :

```
public class DbInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize(PrestationContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        if (!context.Clients.Any())
        {
            var readcsv = File.ReadAllText(@"IorPrestaWebApp\Data\clients.csv");

            string[] csvfilerecord = readcsv.Split('\n');

            foreach (var row in csvfilerecord)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                {
                    var cells = row.Split(';');
                    Client client = new Client
                    {
                        CodeClient = cells[0],
                        Nom = cells[1]
                    };
                    context.Clients.Add(client);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }

        if (!context.Contacts.Any())
        {
            var readcsv = File.ReadAllText(@"IorPrestaWebApp\Data\contacts.csv");

            string[] csvfilerecord = readcsv.Split('\n');

            foreach (var row in csvfilerecord)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                {
                    var cells = row.Split(';');
                    Contact contact = new Contact
                    {
                        Nom = cells[0],
                        Telephone = cells[2],
                        GSM = cells[3],
                        Email = cells[5],
                        CodeClient = cells[13]
                    };
                    context.Contacts.Add(contact);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is `ClientContrat`? I make a test without this property, and got error "The type of navigation property  on the entity type 'Client' is 'Contact[]' which is an array type.. Collection navigation properties cannot be arrays.", after chaning `Contact[]` to `List<Contact>`, it works to insert records

Comment: @TaoZhou I have changed my arrays to lists and i tried without ClientContrat but still the same problem with the foreign key. ClientContrat is an associative class as there is a many-to-many relationship between Client and Contrat.

Comment: Is there a project which could reproduce your issue?

Comment: I will push a part of this project on github in a few days

Answer (score 0):

#Db Context#

```
public class PrestationContext : DbContext
{
    public PrestationContext(DbContextOptions<PrestationContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Prestation> Prestations { get; set; }    
    public DbSet<Domaine> Domaines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employe> Employes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contrat> Contrats { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

 
}
```

#Class#

```
public class Contact
{
    public long ContactID { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string GSM { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Client")] 
    public string CodeClient { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CodeClient")] 
    public Client Client { get; set; }

}

public class Client
{
    public long ClientID { get; set; }
    public string CodeClient { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Adresse { get; set; }
    public bool FeedbackClient { get; set; }
    public bool EncodagePointage { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ClientContrat> ClientContrats { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```